# Storage Allocation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

Can this statement ever fail?

`if (@"Hello") foo();` ?

In other words can there be a situation where in the compiler fails to allocate enough storage space for literals. I know this sounds ridiculous for short length literals but what about really long ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

NSString literals are "allocated" at compile time and form part of the text segment of your program.

**Edit**

To answer the other part of the question, if the compiler fails to allocate enough memory for the literal, the if statement won't fail, but the compilation will.

I don't know what the effective upper limit to the length of a string literal is, but it's bound to be less than `NSIntegerMax` `unichars` because `NSNotFound` is defined as `NSIntegerMax`.  According to the [clang docs](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1StringLiteral.html#a1509ebfcf424c3234a084282f445c3e6), the length in bytes of a string literal is an `unsigned int` and NSString string literals are sequences of `unichars`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure if you try to compile a file with the literal

```
@" ... 1TB worth of characters ... "
```

the compiler will fail. The C standard [available here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says that any compatible compiler needs to support at least 4095 characters per string literal, etc. See Section 5.2.4.1. I'm sure GCC and clang allows much bigger literals.

Comment: is 4095 an upper limit or a lower limit?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add "at least". Please read the standard yourself! I linked to the real document so that you can read it :p